# compare two column values and create 2 more columns based on comparison

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, i would require a column value to be checked if its available in another column values and create 2 more columns based on it.

My Dataframe looks like this :

```
Dept-x  Country Age Category    Dept-y
Math    India   Young   Good    Math,Social,English,Science,French
Math    India   Adult   Good    Math,Social,English,Science,French
Social  Aus     Young   Average Science,Math,Social, English, French
Science Pak     Young   Good    Math,Social,English,Practical,French
Science Pak     Adult   Average Math,Social,Science,French,English
Science Pak     Adult   Good    Science,Math,Social, English, French
```

Expected Dataframe :

```
Top 3   Top all
1             1
1             1
0             1
0             0
1             1
1             1
```

So, in the expected dataframe in addition to the existing columns we would need to add two columns (i.e) Top 3 and Top all.

If the value of Dept-x is available in First 3 values of Dept-y then both Top 3 and Top all should have value as 1.

If the value of Dept-x is not available in First 3 values but exists in Dept-y then Top 3 should be 0 and Top all should be 1.

If the value of Dept-x is not at all available in Dept-y then both Top 3 and Top all should have value a 0.

I would appreciate if some one can help me to achieve this ?

Comment: Why is `Social` not in the top 3? It's the 3rd position in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use list comprehension like this:

```
df['Top 3']=[1 if x in y.split(',')[:3] else 0 for x,y in zip(df['Dept-x'], df['Dept-y'])]
df['Top all']=[1 if x in y else 0 for x,y in zip(df['Dept-x'], df['Dept-y'])]
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try something like this?

```
df['Top 3'] = 0
df['Top all'] = 0
df.loc[df['Dept-x'] in list(df['Dept-y']),'Top all']=1
df.loc[df['Dept-x'] in list(df['Dept-y'])[:3],'Top 3','Top all']=1
```

Comment: @user3483203 Great catch! Updated.

Comment: You don't want the `not` either.  You only want it to be `1` if it *is* in the entire list.

Comment: I'm getting boolean ambiguity errors for the condition `df['Dept-x'] not in list(df['Dept-y'])`; `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous`

Comment: Also this code won't work anyways, I was more just referencing your logic